# PhoneGap App: FB Share via API without FB Popup

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, sdk, share

We plan on building a PhoneGap App and want to give the user the possibility to share information on Facebook.

We wonder if this is possible with the FB JavaScript SDK without leaving our app that means without having FB open its Share Dialog.

Well, and when it is possible does anyone know of an tutorial which kind of describes how we will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for PUBLISH_STREAM permission from the user, there will be no dialog at all.

Comment: Hello wmfairuz, you helped me quite a while ago with the topic maybe you can help me with my current issue, too!? Look here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/17172938/phonegap-fb-connect-plugin-android-os-re-granding-fb-app-every-post Thx, Daniel